# Django Rest Framework - Add pagination(limit on no of objects) on a Viewset view list API, without having a Django Model class

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pagination

I am trying to build a web scraper API, in which it will fetch a list of data from a website and return it. I want to add limit to the result.

My current API path is `/api/country/`

I am looking for something like

`/api/country/?limit=1`

**views**

```
class CovidCountryViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    
    serializer_class = CovidCountrySerializer
    
    def list(self, request):
        summary = CovidDataSraper().fetch_summary_data()
                
        serializer = CovidCountrySerializer(
            instance=summary["data"], many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**serializer.py**

```
class CovidCountrySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    country = serializers.CharField(max_length=256)
    total_cases = serializers.IntegerField()
    active_cases = serializers.IntegerField()
    total_deaths = serializers.IntegerField()
    population = serializers.IntegerField()
    total_recovered = serializers.IntegerField()
    percentate_of_population_infected = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, coerce_to_string=False)
    recovery_rate = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, coerce_to_string=False)
```

**models.py**

```
class CovidCountry:

    def __init__(self, **props):
        fields = ['country', 'total_cases', 'active_cases',
         'total_deaths', 'population', 'total_recovered']

        for field in fields:
            setattr(self, field, props.get(field, None))
```

**urls.py**

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'covid-summary', views.CovidCountryViewSet, basename="covid")

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include((router.urls, 'covid'), namespace='covid'))
]
```

Comment: You can use Django's pagination class as it should work even on non-query set objects as long as it has `count` or `__len__()`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/pagination/#example

Comment: Ok. Will try this